# Group theoretic multiplication table analysis software?

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, math-software, matrix-decomposition, parametrization

Consider a number of different multiplication tables, the results from a graphical parametrisation problem. The goal is to understand which group generates each table or sufficiently close to intermediate results. Decomposition of large multiplicative tables can be useful.

**Does there exist some software to help in analysing such multiplicative tables?**

Comment: The best program I know if you want to handle groups is GAP.

Answer (score 0):

GAP was recommended by Peter. It looks to be most appropriate to group analysis, 4ti2 observed in generator analysis on trees so it may have some functionalities.

**Overviews**

1. [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/) on Groups, Algorithms, Programming -
   a System for Computational Discrete Algebra
2. [4ti2](http://www.4ti2.de/) package for algebraic, geometric and combinatorial problems on linear spaces?

Comment: Separate thing Coq proof assistant -- interesting porgram used to prove four-colour theorem and now Feit Thomson related to classification of finite groups, https://coq.inria.fr/.